# Ramification group - do you know/can produce a simple proof to this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $(K,v)$ be a valuation field, $L$ a finite extension of $K$, and $w$ a valuation of $L$ above $v$. The ramification group of $w$ in $L$ is the subgroup of ${\rm Gal}(L/K)$ of all automorphisms $\sigma$ such that ${\sigma x\over x} = 1 \pmod{\frak p_w}$ for every $x\in L$, where ${\frak p}_w$ is the maximal ideal of the valuation ring of $w$.
Let $\bar K$ be the residual field of $v$, and suppose that ${\rm Char}(\bar K) = p >0$. 
It is known that the ramification group of $w$ is the unique $p$-Sylow subgroup of the inertia group of $w$ (Samuel & Zariski, "Commutative algebra II", p. 76 (23) et p. 77 thm. 24). In particular, the ramification group contains all the automorphisms of order $p^n$ of the inertia group of $w$.

My question is : is there a simple proof of the fact that all the order $p^n$-automorphisms of the inertia group fulfill the equation ${\sigma x\over x} = 1 \pmod{{\frak p}_w}$ for every $x\in L$ ?

N.B: the inertia group of $w$ is the set of all galois automorphisms $\sigma$ such that $\sigma x = x \pmod{{\frak p}_w}$ for all $x\in O_w$.

Comment: Don't we always have $(\dfrac{\sigma x}x)^{q-1}\equiv1\pmod {\mathfrak{p}}$. Here $q=p^f$, $f=$ the inertia degree? So unless $\sigma(x)/x\equiv1$ for all $x$, the order of $\sigma$ necessarily gets an extra factor from $q-1$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen. For the first assertion, I believe you assume that the residual field of $w$ is finite (don't you ?). Regarding your second assertion, I tried to understand but it remains cryptic for me : how do you induce that the order of $\sigma$ must be coprime to $p$ ? are you using some homomorphism ? another hint would be welcome.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen. Regarding the second assertion, I finally got it : you are using the pairing $(x, \sigma) = {\sigma x\over x}$ of Samuel and Zariski and the property $(x, \sigma)(x, \tau) = (x,   \sigma\tau)$.

Comment: Well, for the answer of the question, this is probably what you had in mind : Using the pairing $(x,\sigma) = {\sigma x\over x} \pmod {\frak p}$ and the property $(x,\sigma)(x,\tau) = (x,\sigma\tau),$ then for an automorphism $\sigma$ of order $p^n,$  $(x, \sigma)^{p^n}=1 \pmod{\frak p}$, or $((x, \sigma) - 1)^{p^n} = 0\pmod{\frak p}.$ Thank you for the hint.